# How to convert a dataframe from questions based columns to answers based columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have this example dataframe

```
questions = data.frame(subjects = 1:8,
                       are_you_sad = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2),
                       are_you_worried = c(1,3,1,2,2,4,5,3))
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
questions = data.frame(subjects = 1:8,
                       are_you_sad_1 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                       are_you_sad_2 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1),
                       are_you_sad_3 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),
                       are_you_sad_4 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
                       are_you_sad_5 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                       are_you_worried_1 = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                       are_you_worried_2 = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
                       are_you_worried_3 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                       are_you_worried_4 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                       are_you_worried_5 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
                       )
```

can someone guide me through a simple function to make that possible? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fastDummies::dummy_cols`:

```r
library(fastDummies)
dummy_cols(questions, 
           select_columns = c("are_you_sad", "are_you_worried"), 
           remove_selected_columns = TRUE)
```

Comment: I updated the question with a new dataset. would appreciate the help @Maël

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question, since the answer and problem are different

Comment: ok will do that right away